# More elegant way to do this in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

I've started with Ruby and am finding new, shorter, elegant ways to write code everyday.

In solving Project Euler problems, I've written a lot of code like

```
if best_score < current_score
  best_score = current_score
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Comment: +1 for http://projecteuler.net/

Comment: +1 for doing project euler in Ruby

Comment: hope u'r happy with ur vote status now? ;)

Comment: who r u? did god send u?

Comment: :)) no i just read your comment ))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
best_score = [best_score, current_score].max
```

see: Enumerable.[max](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003134)

---

disclaimer: although this is a little more readable (imho), it's less performant:

```
require 'benchmark'

best_score, current_score, n = 1000, 2000, 100_000

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times do best_score = [best_score, current_score].max end }
  x.report { n.times do 
    best_score = current_score if best_score < current_score 
  end }
end
```

will result in (with ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287)):

```
    user     system      total        real
0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.160333)
0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.030578)
```

Comment: This is swatting a fly with a bat, no?

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that the array can contain any number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks. Enumerable's max method looks great, but I might have to switch to the conditionals at the end when I cross like problem 50 :)

Comment: @The MYYN: I take my comment back. Enumerable#max is great for inline expression substitutions; it's only a little silly for the OP's original use case.

Answer (score 15):

This can be done on a single line:

```
best_score = current_score if best_score < current_score
```

Comment: Putting the conditionals at the end of the statement is just brilliant.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a one-liner?

```
best_score = current_score if best_score < current_score
```

Comment: As a heads up, this is the same as Trevor's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is elegant enough. It's readable and easy to maintain.

If you want shorter, you can go:

```
best_score = current_score if best_score < current_score
```

or

```
best_score = current_score unless best_score >= current_score
```

... but it's not necessarily an improvement in all cases (keep in mind readability).

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't see it above, I lean toward this use of the [ternary operator](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/ruby/examples-ruby-ternary-operator-true-false-syntax):

```
best_score = current_score > best_score ? current_score : best_score
```

and there's also this rather less frequently-encountered version:

```
best_score = (best_score > current_score && best_score) || current_score
```

...which is harder to read, but shows a (to me) slightly unexpected side-effect of short-circuiting. (See [this blog post](http://invisibleblocks.wordpress.com/2007/06/11/rubys-other-ternary-operator/).)

Comment: that's a nice post.. shouldn't the expression be?
best_score = (best_score > current_score && best_score) || current_score

Comment: @Anurag - yes it should, thanks. Inadequate test cases! I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it would qualify as "more elegant", but if you don't want to rewrite the if every time ...

```
def max(b,c)
 if (b < c)
  c
 else
  b
 end
end

best = 10 
current = 20
best = max(best,current)
```

Comment: -1 He's not trying to swap the variables. Reread the question.

Comment: @Tomas: `swap` is a misnomer here. `max` would be a more apt description for what the function actually *does*.

Answer (score 0):

Or this way

```
(current_score > best_score) ? best_score = current_score : best_score
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks just fine the way you have it already. I would only change the comparison so it reads:

*If current score is greater than best score*

You may also create a method and call that. That's more OO to me.

```
 def get_best_score() 
      current_score > best_score ?
          current_score :
          best_score
 end
```

This is what OOP is all about isn't? Hold the object state.

```
best_score = get_best_score()
```

Comment: If we're talking about elegance, best_score = get_best_score would be better. or just score = best_score

Comment: Since you're capturing variables, why not go for a lambda instead?

Comment: I'm more like OO and less Func